# Java Encog SVM Weights

Tags: java, svm, encog

I have trained a SVM classifier using Encog. I have based myself on several examples on Encog GitHub's page. So far so good. But when i try to get the networks weights by using network.dumpWeights(), is doesn't seem to work. Can anybody explain how can I fetch the weights for a SVM type network ?
Kind Regards.